# Is a cambered or symmetrical propeller airfoil more efficient?

Tags: propeller

Is an cambered propeller more efficient than a symmetrical propeller for a low speed airplane?[image]

Comment: Your pictured symmetrical airfoil is actually cambered.

Comment: Yeah!....but hey it looks identical to a symmetrical airfoil

Answer (score 3):

Cambered airfoils are used on propellers as they create less drag for a given Cl than a similar symmetrical airfoil.

The primary use for uncambered or symmetrical airfoils is on flight surfaces that must provide lift in both directions equally well, as in a vertical tail or aerobatic aircraft wing. Propellers only provide forward lift or thrust (ground reverse is too little used to matter) so camber works better.

Comment: You might mention that camber will cause the blade to twist, reducing the benefit of camber. Therefore, propeller airfoils only have light camber.